# "Variable" cannot be resolved to a variable error

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors

I am getting this error in VSCode Java. One of my variables, DriveConstants keeps having the error saying that it cannot be resolved to a variable. DriveConstants is called in Constants and I do not know if I am doing it right. I am new to Java and don't know why this error is happening. Below is the code that I have for DriveSubsystem:

```
//DriveSubsystem

package frc.robot.subsystems;

import frc.robot.Constants;
import edu.wpi.first.math.geometry.Pose2d;
import edu.wpi.first.math.kinematics.DifferentialDriveOdometry;
import edu.wpi.first.math.kinematics.DifferentialDriveWheelSpeeds;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.ADXRS450_Gyro;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.Encoder;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.drive.DifferentialDrive;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.examples.ramsetecommand.Constants.DriveConstants;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.interfaces.Gyro;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.motorcontrol.MotorControllerGroup;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj2.command.SubsystemBase;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.Joystick;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.TimedRobot;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.Timer;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.motorcontrol.VictorSP;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.smartdashboard.SendableChooser;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.smartdashboard.SmartDashboard;

public class DriveSubsystem extends SubsystemBase {
  // The motors on the left side of the drive.
  private VictorSP frontLeftDrive;
  private VictorSP backLeftDrive;
  private VictorSP frontRightDrive;
  private VictorSP backRightDrive;
    
  private final MotorControllerGroup m_leftMotors =
      new MotorControllerGroup(
          new VictorSP(DriveConstants.kLeftMotor1Port),
          new VictorSP(DriveConstants.kLeftMotor2Port));
}
```

//Constants

```
package frc.robot;

import edu.wpi.first.math.kinematics.DifferentialDriveKinematics;

public class Constants {
    public static final class DriveConstants{
        public static final double kTrackwidthMeters=0.96;
        public static final DifferentialDriveKinematics kDriveKinematics = new DifferentialDriveKinematics(kTrackwidthMeters);
    //EXAMPLE VALUES WILL NEED TO CHANGE
        public static final double ksVolts=0.22;
        public static final double ksVoltsSecondPerMeter=1.98;
        public static final double kaVoltSecondsSquaredPerMeter=0.2;
        public static final double kPDriveVel=8.5;
    }

    public static final class AutoConstants {
    //3mph= 1.34112 m/s
    //5mph= 2.2352 m/s
    public static final double kMaxSpeedMetersPerSecond= 1.34112;
    public static final double kMaxSpeedMetersPerSecondSquared=1;
    
    // Reasonable baseline values for a RAMSETE follower in units of meters and seconds
    public static final double kRamseteB = 2;
    public static final double kRamseteZeta = 0.7;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're new to Java my best recommendation is to use IntelliJ not VSCode. Also please share more of your code, as per the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it's best to provide an example that can be easily reproduced.

Comment: a) your class is incomplete and does not compile (syntax errors) b) Where is the class (?) `DriveConstants` is defined? c) does the import work (which line shows the error)? d) do you have all the required jars/files on the class path?

Comment: You asked this same question 5 days ago, then deleted it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75324669.  The answer will be the same as then, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ... or we cannot help you.

Comment: @knittl have added more code. The class should be complete as I just shortened the code so it would not be so line. DriveConstants is defined in Constants. I also get an error with one of the imports saying  it cannot be resolved.

Comment: @StephenC I redid the questions to clarify it

Comment: @Macattack your second code block contains the same class again. Are you sure you pasted the correct code? The question is still missing the definition of `DriveConstants`.

Comment: Nope.  It needs to be a minimal reproducible example.  You have a bazzilion references to classes that are not available to use.  We can't compile it. If we cannot compile it it is not **reproducible**.  Even if it is all of >your< code.

Comment: @knittl fixed the constant code

Comment: Your Constants is `frc.robot.Constants`, but your import is `edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.examples.ramsetecommand.Constants.DriveConstants`. If you want to import something, you need to provide the correct, fully-qualified name. Even though I can see imports for both FQN. Which one is the correct one? If `DriveConstants` from the `frc.robot.Constants` class should be used, then either import it, or qualify it: `Constants.DriveConstants.kLeftMotor1Port`, etc.

Comment: And besides, this code contains no **variable** named `DriveConstants` in this code.  But you have a **class** called `DriveConstants` ... and you appear to be importing a second `DriveConstants` class as well ... from a different package.  Maybe *that* is your mistake.  (Is your code trying to find / use constants that are declared in the other class?)  Having two classes with the same name is asking for trouble.

Comment: @knittl I am following this website to implement an automounts mode that follows a trajectory  [link] (https://docs.wpilib.org/en/stable/docs/software/pathplanning/trajectory-tutorial/creating-drive-subsystem.html) So I do not know why I am getting this error

Comment: @Macattack you get the error because your package names do not match when defining and when importing the class. Also, there are two classes with the same name (but in different packages), which might add to the confusion

Comment: For the record.  *"I redid the questions to clarify it"* - Deleting a reposting a question for any reason is considered bad manners (at best) on StackOverflow.  The correct way to do it is to EDIT the *existing* question to address the points that the comments raised.

Comment: @StephenC so would I just need to change the name of the class?

Comment: That would be a good idea.  I can't tell you if that is all that you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to import frc.robot.Constants.DriveConstants;